# Eclipse SonarLint: Connect to SonarQube via HTTPS - PKIX path building failed

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube, sonarlint

I'm trying to connect my Eclipse SonarLint plugin to my SonarQube server (that uses HTTPS) but I cannot reach the server due to certificate problems.

When I try to connect to the SonarQube server (using the SonarLint plugin's wizard) I get the following error message:

> PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

[image: sonarlint wizard]

**What I've tried so far:**

- I know this problem is related to the certificates of the HTTPS server that the SonarQube is running on but although I imported the certificates into the keystore of my JRE the problem persists.
- When I try to run an analysis in a gradle task that sends the results to the same SonarQube server everything works fine so I think the imported certificates are ok.
- I also tried to import the certificates in the eclipse jre (the one that is mentioned in the eclipse.ini file) but that doesn't fix it either.
- Configuring a different trust-store (using the javax.net.ssl.trustStore vm argument in the eclipse.ini file) or deleting this argument doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an Eclipse issue. After **installing a clean, new Eclipse** (same version that I used before) it works without any problems. I just needed to import the certificates into the JRE that was mentioned in the eclipse.ini file and it worked.

I don’t realy know why this solved the issue, but it seems to be reproducable.